# Create object of main class which in turns instantiate its other member classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Is there any way that we can create object of only Main class which contains other classes as well.

```
 public class City
{
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public string CItyName { get; set; }
}
  public class State
{
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }
}`
 public class CurrentPresident
{
    public int PresidentId { get; set; }
    public string PresidentName { get; set; }
}
 public class Country
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public CurrentPresident President { get; set; }
    public IList<State> States { get; set; }
    public IList<City> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

I have four different classes and my Country class holds there different classes as members
Now I wants to create object of only Country class not other classes which are inside of Country class.

```
Country country=new Country();
```

To make it more clear I do not wants to create objects of City, State and CurrentPresident classes. All I wants to create object of Country Class which in turns also instantiates other classes which are inside the Country class.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You have already posted the solution: `Country country=new Country();`. If you also want to initialize the other types you should provide proper constructors or inline initialization.

Comment: @Tim thanks for quick reply but my statement only creates object of Country class not other classes which are inside Country class.

Comment: If I am putting this line Country count = new Country();
            count.President.PresidentId = 1;                         I will get error because President is not instantiated.

Comment: You can always provide constructors in your classes which initialize the fields in the way you want. So you could provide an empty constructor(`public Country(){States=new List<State>();CurrentPresident=new President();...}`) where you initialize objects as desired.

Comment: It is pointless to access a president that is yet not defined. So imho it would even be a bug to provide a default-president for every country. If you want to know a country's president you have to specify it first. For example: `c.President = new CurrentPresident{ PresidentId = 1, PresidentName = "Obama" };`

Comment: well, its still not working. First it is creating object of Country and in the default constructor as you have mentioned I am creating objects of childs classes but not working . Still other objects are coming as null.

Comment: @user1301587: You are getting very different answers from a lot of people. Please can you improve the question, as it is unclear of what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Although unsure of the reasons, if you don't want to create the other objects when you create a `Country`, make the getters inside the `Country` return a private field and initiliase the field in your getter. This way the properties will only be created the first time you access them and not in the ctor of Country and since they're created when you access them you don't need to create them outside of Country.

```
public class Country
{
    ....
    public CurrentPresident President 
    { 
        get
        {
            if (_president == null)
            {
                _president = new CurrentPresident();
            }
            return _president;
        } 
        //no setter as outside objects don't need to create them
    }
    ....

    private CurrentPresident _president
}
```

Comment: This seems to be working fine..still need more testing. Thanks a lot artm.

Answer (score 0):

Your country class should be follows

```
public class Country
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public CurrentPresident President { get; set; }
    public IList<State> States { get; set; }
    public IList<City> Cities { get; set; }
    public Country()
    {
          States = new List<State>();
          Cities =new List<City>();
    }
}
```

Not that it will not work when you will use object initialize. There you need to use some trick.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to create a Country, but not populate the contents of the class. In other words, you want the country to be empty, and usable when it is created.

You can use a constructor to achieve this:

```
public class Country
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public CurrentPresident President { get; set; }
    public IList<State> States { get; set; }
    public IList<City> Cities { get; set; }

    public Country()
    {
       this.CountryId = 0;
       this.CurrentPresident = null; // Country is brand new, no president elected :-)
       this.States = new List<State>();
       this.Cities = new List<City>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate all your inner objects inside the main object constructor. For example:

```
public class City
{
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public string CItyName { get; set; }
}
public class State
{
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }
}
public class CurrentPresident
{
    public int PresidentId { get; set; }
    public string PresidentName { get; set; }
}
public class Country
{
    public Country()
    {
        this.President = new CurrentPresident();
        this.States = new List<State>();
        this.Cities = new List<City>();
    }

    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public CurrentPresident President { get; set; }
    public IList<State> States { get; set; }
    public IList<City> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

Bear in mind that although each object exists, all of them inside are still empty (no `PresidentId`, empty `List`s, etc.).

You may want to create different constructors with different parameters, depending on what you need. For example, you may want to provide the `CurrentPresident` when creating the `Country` so it always has valid data.